# maintain viewstate for html elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a generic 'form page' user control that we use that allows editors to insert whatever kind of html form they want to inside of it, and it handles all of the form posts.

My question is, is there a way to store the vanilla non-asp form entries in the viewstate or otherwise save the entries on a form post, in the case that some server-side validation fails, so they can be restored when the page refreshes?

We currently already do upfront javascript validation that catches the majority of the input errors. We store all the form post data in a db before we do further processing, and some of the entries contain junk (spam we wish to ignore) or only partial info (i'm assuming those are cases where the user doesn't have javascript enabled). I'm trying to catch these last fringe cases so we do not process them.

Comment: What do you mean by _"non-asp form entries"_? Can you give an example?

Comment: just vanilla `<input>` tags inside of a `<form>`. part of the functionality of the user control is that it lets editors drop in their own html forms that they've written and the form page will render it along with all of the other supporting stuff it needs, as well as handles setting the form action, doing form validation, etc.

Comment: So, if understand correctly, the problem is because these elements do not have "runat=server", so they are not visible on postback? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: yes. the user control has no idea what kind of form html it is loading until a page is hit, and it pulls the data for it from our cms. the form html is just straight up html, nothing asp related. on a form post, if back end validation fails, we display an error but maintain no state (since the input elements aren't asp controls)

Comment: How do you save the form input? Do you simply dump the entire form into the db with the values inside? Is the code aware of the separate form elements?

Comment: I ask because I have a couple of ideas, but I want to make sure they are relevant before presenting them.

Comment: we save the id of the page being loaded, and a ToString() representation of the Request.Form object. 

the code itself for the control doesn't care about named form input fields are in the form. they are parsed in a separate process that can be determined by the editors.

Comment: OK. Then in cases where the server-side validation fails, you can add a literal control to the form (or already have one there). Then just dump the .ToString() representation of the Request.Form object into that literal. This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, 
1>User fills form
2>Clicks submit
3>Error detected on the server side
4>The Html posted back should contain the form i already filled with an error message on top.

Have you considered using JQuery Ajax?

The jquery ajax will post to a web method. The web method returns a JSON response. If the response is success redirect user to the next page, else show error on top of the page.

That way you don't need to maintain the state of the user input (since it is never lost).

Comment: i'll probably go with this approach

Answer (score 1):

If you dont know what the form fields are ahead of time then I would reccomend that you look into partial postbacks.

Or else post the forms via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you could store the text HTML in

```
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hid1" runat="server" />
```

this will be passed in View State